# Generate DTO classes from XSD or by simple POJO classes

Tags: java, json, rest, soap, xsd

I have been working with an enterprise application, where we use SOAP and RESTful Webservices. At some point we have planned to migrate SOAP to RESTful service in order to produce JSON MediaType as response. For SOAP we have been generating dto classes from XSD files. In case of Restful implementation i can directly use POJO classes as my request and response. 
Here XML definition is not required. So is it necessary to create new DTO classes generated from xsd or can i create simple POJO classes and use as request and response.

I can configure POJO maping in web.xml

```
<servlet>  
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
</servlet>
```

Comment: Are you looking for [XJC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/xjc.html)?

Comment: No. I have been using xjc to compile xsd to java classes. Am looking for better way of organizing my code i.e., to use dto as simple POJO or create same dto from xsd files.

Comment: You don't consider schema-derived classes to be DTOs? I'm just trying to understand what actually your problem is.

Comment: Yes you are correct. if am working with JSON type data. I think it is not required to generate clasess from xsd. I can directly create POJOclass and use it for service request and response.

Comment: I have the work flow like DTO->VO->BO->DAO. If i expose POJO in service request and response,here am trying to remove the conversion from DTO to VO process

Comment: Your JAXB POJOs generally should work with the Jackson serializer. Have you tried using them? If so are you having any problems? If so, post the problem. If not, I think you may be asking a premature question

Comment: Yes. Instead of Jackson serializer, am using genson serializer to map my request and response. And it is working fine as well.  Am just confused that can i directly use VO (POJO) as request and response classes or is there a standard to maintain this POJO's (JAXB) should be generated from xsd files and convert it to VO classes to my utils(using Dozer Mapping). I am making sure that am stick to pure webservice implementations